# Add record in core data with array of entity with editable functionality

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship

Please look at the issue I'm facing.

I have one activity to perform with following features.

With `CoreData` I like to add employees records. Records having following attributes:

1. employee name(`NSString`)
2. empnumber(`NSString`)
3. phoneNumber(arrayType)
4. attendance(array type).

and after I save these record if I'd like to edit phonenumber ao attendence i can do so and save back to CoreData.

Please help me out. What is the good approach of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you haven't done anything to work with core data in your project? I really think the best way to learn how to work with core data is to read AND follow one of the many excellent tutorials found on google.

Follow something like this tutorial http://timroadley.com/2012/02/09/core-data-basics-part-1-storyboards-delegation/ and I believe you will be able to get your project started.

Comment: i thank you for goog tutorial, but i need more than that ,with one record of employee i shoul have all these entries with multiple phone numbers and attendences, when i go in editing mod i can edit phone number list or delet it  .

Comment: OK. I'm not sure I understand how you want to use this, but i think you should create a data model with three entities. Employee, PhoneNumber and Attendance. Then make one-to-many relationship from Employee to PhoneNumber and Attendance. Then one Employee can have as many phone numbers and attendances as you would like. How you work with relationships is also explained here: http://timroadley.com/2012/02/19/core-data-basics-part-4-relationships/ Part 3 of that tutorial explains editing and deleting.